# Macbook Pro not charging

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power

My 2009 Macbook pro is not charging.  I recently bought a new power adapter and when I plug it in the computer starts up fine although the date is set back to Jan 1 2001.  When I click on the battery icon I see a message saying that it is not charging even though the green light is on and the the icon shows the charging symbol. It also always says the battery is at 42%.  The battery has been replaced once about 2 years ago.  When I unplug the power adapter it immediately dies.  Any ideas?

Comment: is the power adapter rated for your computer?  volts needs to be exact, watts (or amps) the charger needs to be at least as large as required by the MBP but may exceed.  Short of that you will have to try a new battery, make sure its returnable tho in case it's not the issue.

Comment: The old one was 85watts and so is the new one.

Comment: SMC is responsible for that, so did you reset it ?

Comment: The loss of Date indicates your battery has been completely drained. What does it show in About this Mac about it.

Comment: To slightly restate Buscar웃SD's fine comment, can you open About This Mac and check the battery from there?  The steps are probably to go to the Apple menu, select About This Mac, click System Report, find Hardware > Power and read the battery Health Information, especially the Condition.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the SMC.

From https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295:

> On Mac notebooks with non-removable battery Mac notebook computers
>   that have a battery you should not remove include: MacBook Pro (Early
>   2009) and later, all models of MacBook Air, MacBook (Late 2009), and
>   MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015). To reset the SMC: Shut down the
>   computer. Plug in the MagSafe or USB-C power adapter to a power source
>   and to your computer. On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side)
>   Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.
>   Release all the keys and the power button at the same time. Press the
>   power button to turn on the computer. On MagSafe power adapters, the
>   LED might change states or temporarily turn off when you reset the
>   SMC.